# Drag and Drop attachments from Outlook into a web app?

Tags: drag-and-drop

Is there a way to drag and drop email attachments (not the email itself, the attached file) from Outlook into a Javascript web app?

All of my searches have been in vain, leading me to think a browser add-on is necessary, but I hope there's an easier way!

Comment: I think you need to find a way how to dag and drop files into a JS web app first.

Comment: It works to drag and drop a file from the desktop, but Outlook attachment to web app doesn't work.